# Where's "Unsubscribe" on the Workshop page of America's Army in Steam?

Tags: steam-workshop, americas-army-3

[On July 3 2021, Cadence answered](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/387586)

> If you want to clear out Workshop items to free up space on your computer, you'll want to locate them in the respective games' Workshop pages and choose "Unsubscribe".

I accessed the Workshop page for America's Army. But I don't see "Unsubscribe".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the page for the item you want to unsubscribe from, to see the Unsubscribe option.

---

Or go to the list of your items / your items from this game, and there should be a list of "Unsubscibe" options.

The list should be in Community -> Workshop:

Below the "Browse All Workshops" section, your profile picture should be beside a "Your Workshop Files" link. Click that and there's a list of the items you have.